# Any way to filter IP's when logging queries? (BIND 9.3)

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind, logging, filter

I would like to record queries to my DNS **from a particular ip**. Is this possible?

Right now I have this:

```
channel query_log {
                file "/var/named/data/queries.log" versions 2 size 1G;
                severity debug 3;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-time yes;
        };

category queries { query_log;};
```

As you may imagine, the file "queries.log" grows at an extremely fast rate on our busy network.  I just would like to log the queries from a particular ip.  Is there a way to do this using any channel option?  I thought about creating a separate view (to match the host I want to record) but you can oly have one "logging" option in named.conf (not inside the views) :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is any way that you can configure bind to do the filtering you want.

I can think of two ways you could achieve the result I believe you want.

Setup bind query logging, keep only 1 versions, and reduce the size of the logs you are keeping.

Leave a command like below running to constantly monitor changes to the query log and store the information you want to save to a separate file.

```
tail --follow --retry /var/named/data/queries.log \
      | grep 'ip.ad.dd.res' > /var/named/data/queries_ip.ad.dd.res.log
```

The second method would be to just use tcpdump to capture all incoming requests from that host.  You would use a command like this.

```
tcpdump -n dst port 53 and src host ip.ad.dd.res > /var/log/dns_ip.ad.dd.res.log
```

Comment: Thanks again Zoredache.  The tail idea sounds good and that's what I'm going to do then.  I thought about tcpdump but I wanted to see if it was possible using BIND (I like the format of the query log that BIND produces) and thought that maybe there was some switch I was missing but indeed it seems there's no way to perform the filtering natively.  Thanks again!